# Properties of the inverse Laplacian operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, laplacian, differential-operators

The inverse of the Laplacian is given by
$$(-\Delta)^{-1} u(x) = C \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u(x-y) \frac{1}{|y|^{n-2}} dy$$
where $n$ is the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I would like to learn more about this operator as I have often seen the formula stated but not explained. For example, we can motivate fractional powers of the Laplacian by use of the Fourier transform. I am looking for something similar.

Some of the questions I have been thinking about are:

1. How is it derived and is there a reason it is identical to the fundamental solution of the Laplacian?
2. For what function spaces for $u$ is it valid? I assume that $u$ must belong to a space such that the Laplacian is invertible (i.e. a bijection), but for which spaces is this true?
3. I assume that we gain two degrees of regularity through this operator, but how is this proven? What is the image of this operator?

I have struggled to find this information in any textbooks. Can anyone suggest some textbooks or references I can read in this direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A quick heuristic.**

Just to be clear, we recall that for all $u\in\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$, up to some abuse of notations : $$\mathcal{F}(-\Delta u)(\xi) = |\xi|^2 \mathcal{F}u(\xi)\text{.}$$

Here, I define the Fourier transform as
$$ \mathcal{F}f(\xi) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) e^{-i\,x\cdot\xi} \mathrm{~d}x\,\text{, (}f\in\mathrm{L}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)\text{, } \xi\in\mathbb{R}^n\text{).}$$

Therefore, if one wants to solve
$$-\Delta u =f\,\text{, in } \mathbb{R}^n.$$

One should have then, at least morally,
$$u(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \mathcal{F}f(\xi) \cdot \frac{1}{|\xi|^2} e^{i\,x\cdot\xi} \mathrm{~d}\xi = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left( \xi\mapsto\mathcal{F}f(\xi) \cdot \frac{1}{|\xi|^2} \right) = [f \ast \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\xi\mapsto|\xi|^{-2})](x). $$

Thus, the question reduce to know if one can prove (and give a sense to) the equality

$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\xi\mapsto|\xi|^{-2})(x) = C_n \frac{1}{|x|^{n-2}}.$$

Notice that, at the first glance, such representation formula involving such kernel makes sense only when $n\geqslant 3$. For $n=2$, one has to replace $\frac{1}{|x|^{n-2}}$ by $\log(|x|)$.

**Answers to the post.**

Now, I am starting by answering (partially) to the first part of your second question.

> 2. **For what function spaces for u
>    is it valid?** I assume that u
>    must belong to a space such that the Laplacian is invertible (i.e. a bijection), but for which spaces is this true?

You can make sense of the right hand-side integral for Schwartz functions, $u\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, or non-negative measurable functions, $u\in\mathrm{L}^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (allowing the integral to take infinite values).

The question of actual function spaces on which it is well defined and such that it induces a bijection is much more delicate. I will adress this issue a bit later.

> 1. How is it derived and is there a reason it is identical to the fundamental solution of the Laplacian?

It is actually the same as the fundamental solution. In fact, we can go a bit further and also find a similar way to identify the fractional Laplacian as such kind of convolution operator.

We define the following subspace of Schwartz functions for convenience
$$\mathcal{S}_0(\mathbb{R}^n) := \{\,u\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)\,|\, 0\notin \mathrm{supp}\,\mathcal{F}u\,\}$$

- **Definition**: *For $s\in\mathbb{R}$, we define the fractional Laplacian of order $\frac{s}{2}$, for any *suitable* $u$, as
  $$ (-\Delta)^\frac{s}{2} u := \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\xi\mapsto |\xi|^{s} \mathcal{F}u(\xi)). $$
  In particular, the definition makes sense for any $u\in \mathcal{S}_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and one even has in this case,
  $$ (-\Delta)^\frac{s}{2} u \in \mathcal{S}_0(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n). $$*
  This is left as a tedious (but not hard) exercise.

We are particularly interested here by the behavior of the fractional Laplacian
$$ (-\Delta)^{-\frac{s}{2}}\,\text{, } s>0\text{.} $$

Here is the main result you are looking for:

- **Proposition**: *Let $n\geqslant 2$, for any $s\in(0,n)$, we have the following equality in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$
  \begin{align*}
      \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{\left\lvert\xi\right\rvert^s} e^{-ix\cdot\xi}\,\mathrm{d}\xi = (2\pi)^\frac{n}{2}\frac{2^\frac{n-s}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{n-s}{2}\right)}{2^\frac{s}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)}\cdot \frac{1}{\left\lvert x\right\rvert^{n-s}}\text{ ,}
  \end{align*}
  i.e., for all $\varphi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$,
  $$ \left\langle \mathcal{F}\left[|\cdot|^{-s}\right], \varphi\right\rangle = (2\pi)^\frac{n}{2}\frac{2^\frac{n-s}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{n-s}{2}\right)}{2^\frac{s}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)} \cdot \left\langle |\cdot|^{-(n-s)}, \varphi\right\rangle\text{.}$$*

I propose here a very elementary proof with a lot of details, for other proofs one may consult **[1, Proposition 1.29]** or **[2, Section 2.4.3, Theorem 2.4.6]**. Setting $s=2$ gives the result you are looking for.

- ***Proof of the proposition***: Let $s \in(0, n)$, and $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \setminus\{0\}$. We denote by $\Gamma$ the usual Gamma function defined for any $x>0$ by
  \begin{align*}
      \Gamma(x)=\int_{0}^{+\infty} t^{x-1} e^{-t} \mathrm{~d} t\text{ .}
  \end{align*}
  We clearly have
  \begin{align*}
      \Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)=\int_{0}^{+\infty} t^{\frac{s}{2}-1} e^{-t} \mathrm{~d} t\text{ .}
  \end{align*}
  Since $\xi \neq 0, t \longmapsto t\left\lvert\xi\right\rvert^{2}$ is a diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}_{+}$, of class $C^{1}$, we deduce
  \begin{align*}
      \Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left\lvert\xi\right\rvert^{s} t^{\frac{s}{2}-1} e^{-t\left\lvert\xi\right\rvert^{2}} \mathrm{~d} t\text{ ,}
  \end{align*}
  so that
  \begin{align*}
      \frac{1}{\left\lvert\xi\right\rvert^s}=\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)} \int_{0}^{+\infty} t^{\frac{\pi}{2}-1} e^{-t\left\lvert\xi\right\rvert^{2}} \mathrm{~d} t \text{ . }
  \end{align*}
  Now, let $\phi \in \mathcal{S}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$. First we consider the function
  \begin{align*}
  F: \mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}  \times \mathbb{R}^{n} &\longrightarrow \mathbb{C} \\
  (t, \xi) &\longmapsto \frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)} t^{\frac{s}{2}-1} e^{-t\left\lvert\xi\right\rvert^{2}} \phi(\xi)
  \end{align*}
  so that $F$ satisfies near the origin
  \begin{align*}
      F(t, \xi) \underset{(0,0)}{\sim} \frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)} t^{\frac{s}{2}-1} \phi(0)
  \end{align*}
  And for any $\alpha \geqslant 0, \beta \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n},$ writing $\xi^{\beta}=\xi_{1}^{\beta_{1}} \ldots \xi_{n}^{\beta_{n}}$, we see from the fact that $\phi\in \mathcal{S}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$ that
  \begin{align*}
      t^{\alpha} \xi^{\beta} F(t, \xi) \underset{t,\left\lvert\xi\right\rvert \rightarrow+\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0 \text{ .}
  \end{align*}
  We deduce that $F \in \mathrm{L}^{1}\left(\mathbb{R}_{+} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$. Hence, applying Fubini-Lebesgue's Theorem, one has :
  \begin{align*}
      \int_{\mathbb{R}_{+}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)} t^{\frac{s}{2}-1} e^{-t\left\lvert\xi\right\rvert^{2}} \phi(\xi) \mathrm{d} \xi \mathrm{d} t=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}_{+}} \frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)} t^{\frac{s}{2}-1} e^{-t\left\lvert\xi\right\rvert^{2}} \mathrm{~d} t\right) \phi(\xi) \mathrm{~d} \xi \text{, }
  \end{align*}
  thus, one can write
  \begin{align*}
      \frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)} \int_{0}^{+\infty} t^{\frac{s}{2}-1}\left\langle e^{-t\left\lvert\cdot\right\rvert^{2}}, \phi\right\rangle \mathrm{d} t=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \frac{\phi(\xi)}{\left\lvert\xi\right\rvert^{s}} \mathrm{~d} \xi\text{ .}
  \end{align*}
  Note that the latter integral is absolutely convergent (one may use polar coordinates and the decreasing properties of $\phi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$). Now, we introduce the distribution $T_s \in \mathcal{S}^{\prime}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$ which is defined for any $\phi \in \mathcal{S}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$ by
  \begin{align*}
  \langle T_s, \phi\rangle &:=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \frac{\phi(\xi)}{\left\lvert\xi\right\rvert^{s}} \mathrm{~d} \xi \\
  &=\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)} \int_{0}^{+\infty} t^{\frac{s}{2}-1}\left\langle e^{-t\left\lvert\cdot\right\rvert^{2}}, \phi\right\rangle \mathrm{~d} t\text{ .}
  \end{align*}
  We want to compute $\mathcal{F}T_s$, for $\phi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, we use the definition of the Fourier transform on $\mathcal{S}'$ which gives
  \begin{align*}
      \langle \mathcal{F}T_s, \phi\rangle &:= \langle T_s, \mathcal{F}\phi\rangle\\
  &=\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)} \int_{0}^{+\infty} t^{\frac{s}{2}-1}\left\langle e^{-t\left\lvert\cdot\right\rvert^{2}}, \mathcal{F}\phi\right\rangle \mathrm{~d} t\\
  &=\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)} \int_{0}^{+\infty} t^{\frac{s}{2}-1}\left\langle \mathcal{F}\left[ e^{-t\left\lvert\cdot\right\rvert^{2}}\right], \phi\right\rangle \mathrm{~d} t\\
  &=\frac{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)} \int_{0}^{+\infty} t^{\frac{s}{2}-1}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{t^\frac{n}{2}}e^{-\frac{\left\lvert x \right\rvert^2}{4t}} \phi(x)\mathrm{~d}x \right) \mathrm{~d} t\text{ ,}
  \end{align*}
  where we used the well known fact $\mathcal{F}\left[ e^{-t\left\lvert\cdot\right\rvert^{2}}\right] (x) = \frac{\pi^\frac{n}{2}}{t^\frac{n}{2}}e^{-\frac{\left\lvert x \right\rvert^2}{4t}}$, for all $t>0$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Now, we consider the function
  \begin{align*}
  G: \mathbb{R}_{+}^{*} \times \mathbb{R}^{n} & \longrightarrow \mathbb{C} \\
  (t, x) & \longmapsto t^{\frac{s}{2}-\frac{n}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{|x|^{2}}{4 t}} \phi(x)
  \end{align*}
  using the change of variable $(t, x) \longmapsto(t, \sqrt{t} x)$ which is a diffeomorphism of class $C^{1}$ over $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{*} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$, with jacobian $(t, x) \longmapsto t^{\frac{n}{2}},$ we have
  \begin{align*}
  G(t, \sqrt{t} x) t^{\frac{n}{2}} \underset{(0,0)}{\sim} t^{\frac{s}{2}-1} \phi(0)
  \end{align*}
  And for any $\alpha \geqslant 0, \beta \in \mathbb{N}^{n}$, writing $x^{\beta}=x_{1}^{\beta_{1}} \ldots x_{n}^{\beta_{n}},$ we see that
  \begin{align*}
  t^{\alpha} x^{\beta} G(t, \sqrt{t} x) t^{\frac{n}{2}} \underset{t,|x| \rightarrow+\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0
  \end{align*}
  Since the composition with a diffeomorphism does not change the integrability, we deduce that $G \in \mathrm{L}^{1}\left(\mathbb{R}_{+} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$. Hence applying Fubini-Lebesgue's Theorem, we have
  \begin{align*}
  \left\langle\mathcal{F} T_s, \phi\right\rangle=\frac{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\left(\int_{0}^{+\infty} t^{\frac{s}{2}-\frac{n}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{|x|^{2}}{4 t}} \mathrm{~d} t\right) \phi(x) \mathrm{~d} x \text{ .}
  \end{align*}
  So it remains to compute for any $x\neq 0$, the integral
  \begin{align*}
      \int_{0}^{+\infty} t^{\frac{s}{2}-\frac{n}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{|x|^{2}}{4 t}} \mathrm{~d} t \text{ .}
  \end{align*}
  First since $t\longmapsto\frac{1}{t}$ is a $C^1$-diffeormorphism with jacobian $t\longmapsto \frac{1}{t^2}$, one has
  \begin{align*}
      \int_{0}^{+\infty} t^{\frac{s}{2}-\frac{n}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{|x|^{2}}{4 t}} \mathrm{~d} t = \int_{0}^{+\infty} t^{\frac{n}{2}-\frac{s}{2}-1} e^{-t\frac{|x|^{2}}{4}} \mathrm{~d} t
  \end{align*}
  so that applying the result from the beginning of the proof to $\xi=\frac{x}{2}$, and changing $s$ into $n-s$, we finally have
  \begin{align*}
      \int_{0}^{+\infty} t^{\frac{s}{2}-\frac{n}{2}-1} e^{-\frac{|x|^{2}}{4 t}} \mathrm{~d} t = \frac{2^{n-s}\Gamma\left(\frac{n-s}{2}\right)}{\left\lvert{x}\right\rvert^{n-s}}\text{ .}
  \end{align*}
  The result follows from the equality ${\pi^\frac{n}{2}2^{n-s}}=(2\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{2^\frac{n-s}{2}}{2^{\frac{s}{2}}}$. $\blacksquare$

We get back on the well-define character and the boundedness of the fractional Laplacian  $(-\Delta)^{-\frac{s}{2}}\,\text{, } s>0\text{.}$

> 2. **For what function spaces for u
>    is it valid?** I assume that u
>    must belong to a space such that the Laplacian is invertible (i.e. a bijection), but for which spaces is this true?

The following result gives the $\mathrm{L}^p-\mathrm{L}^q$ boundedness. This is a sharp result and one cannot expect any other kind of boundedness on Lebesgues spaces.

- **Theorem (Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev Inequality)**: *Let $s\in(0,n)$, and let $p,q\in(1,+\infty)$ such that
  \begin{align*}
      \frac{1}{q}=\frac{1}{p}-\frac{s}{n}\text{ .}
  \end{align*}
  Then the following linear convolution operator
  \begin{align*}
      (-\Delta)^{-\frac{s}{2}}   :   \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)   &   \longrightarrow     \mathrm{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)\\
                                                      f   &   \longmapsto    \left[    x\mapsto \frac{2^\frac{n-s}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{n-s}{2}\right)}{(2\pi)^\frac{n}{2}2^\frac{s}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}    \frac{1}{\left\lvert{x-y}\right\rvert^{n-s}}f(y)\mathrm{~d}y \right]
  \end{align*}
  is also a well defined bounded linear operator from $\mathrm{L}^p({\mathbb{R}^n})$ to $\mathrm{L}^q({\mathbb{R}^n})$, i.e. there exists a constant $C>0$ depending on $n, s, p$ and $q$ such that for any $f\in\mathrm{L}^p({\mathbb{R}^n})$, one has*
  \begin{align*}
      \lVert (-\Delta)^{-\frac{s}{2}} f\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^q({\mathbb{R}^n})}\leqslant C \left\lVert f\right\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^p({\mathbb{R}^n})}.
  \end{align*}

See **[3, Section 1.2.1, Theorem 1.2.3]** for a proof and the sharpness or the result, or **[1, Theorem 1.38]** for the simpler case $p=2$. I don't give any proof here because it requires too much additional technology.

**Notice, since the result is sharp, one NEVER has $\mathrm{L}^p$-$\mathrm{L}^p$ boundedness of $(-\Delta)^{-1}$, even if $p=2$.**

**In particular, the operator $(-\Delta)^{-1}$ NEVER MAPS $\mathrm{L}^p$ to $\mathrm{W}^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ !** (Here, $\mathrm{W}^{2,p}$, also denoted sometimes $\mathrm{H}^{2,p}$, is the standard Sobolev space made of $\mathrm{L}^p$ functions such that all weak derivatives up to the order $2$ also lies in $\mathrm{L}^p$).

> 2. For what function spaces for u
>    is it valid? ***I assume that u
>    must belong to a space such that the Laplacian is invertible (i.e. a bijection), but for which spaces is this true?***
> 3. ***I assume that we gain two degrees of regularity through this operator, but how is this proven? What is the image of this operator?***

Those two questions are deeply related and the possible answers are highly non-trivial.

The main idea comes from the next very important theorem, that says that essentially $\mathrm{L}^p$ norm of the Laplacian contains all the informations about the $\mathrm{L}^p$ of all second order derivatives, so that knowledge of the laplacian or all the second order derivatives makes no differences on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

- **Theorem (Schauder estimates)**: *Let $p\in(1,+\infty)$. There exists a constant $C>0$ depending on $n$ and $p$, such that for all $u\in \mathrm{W}^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)(=\mathrm{H}^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^n))$, one has
  $$\lVert \nabla^2 u\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)} \leqslant C\lVert \Delta u\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}\leqslant C \lVert \nabla^2 u\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}.$$*

For a proof with all the steps, check for instance **[2, Definition 5.1.13 & Proposition 5.1.14 p.325, Proposition 5.1.17 p.328, Corollary 5.2.8 p.340, Exercise 5.2.10 (a) p.354]**.

- **Definition (of Homogeneous Sobolev spaces)**: *Let $p\in(1,+\infty)$. We define the **homogeneous** Sobolev space of order $2$ over $\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to be the following completion in tempered distribution modulo polynomials
  $$\dot{\mathrm{H}}^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) := \widehat{\mathrm{H}^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)}^{ \lVert \nabla^2 \cdot\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^p}}\subset \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)/\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n).$$
  We set $\lVert u \rVert_{\dot{\mathrm{H}}^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)} := \lVert \nabla^2 u \rVert_{\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}$.*

The reason why the completion is taken in tempered distributions modulo polynomials, is that we want the semi-norm $\lVert \nabla^2 \cdot\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^p}$ to be an actual norm. That is, $\lVert \nabla^2 \cdot\rVert_{\mathrm{L}^p}$ does not distinguishe two elements of $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if they differ from a polynomial of degree $1$.

Notice also that we ***NEVER*** have $\dot{\mathrm{H}}^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset \mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

In this case, reasoning by density, we obtain the following result from the Schauder estimates above.

- **Theorem**: *Let $p\in(1,+\infty)$. Then $$ (-\Delta)\,:\, \dot{\mathrm{H}}^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)\longrightarrow \mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n) $$ is an isomorphism of Banach spaces.*

However, due to the quotient structure involving polynomials, one can no longer compute $(-\Delta)^{-1}f$ pointwise using the convolution formula. The problem being that there is in general no way to choose canonically the polynomial part to obtain a representative being an element of $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$. This is a really technical and hard question.

However, in the specific case $(1,\frac{n}{2})$, thanks to the **Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality** when $s=2$, we can modify the construction to deal with actual elements of $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

- **Definition (of Homogeneous Sobolev spaces)**: *Let $p\in(1,\frac{n}{2})$. We (re)define the **homogeneous** Sobolev space of order $2$ over $\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to be
  $$\dot{\mathrm{H}}^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) := \{\, u\in\mathrm{L}^{\frac{pn}{n-2p}}(\mathbb{R}^n)\,|\,\lVert \nabla^2 u \rVert_{\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}<+\infty\,\}.$$
  We still set $\lVert u \rVert_{\dot{\mathrm{H}}^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)} := \lVert \nabla^2 u \rVert_{\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}$.*

One can check that this space is a Banach space for the norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{\dot{\mathrm{H}}^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)}$, and that Schwartz functions are dense for such a construction.

In this specific case, there is no more ambiguity, and one can compute for any $f\in\mathrm{L}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, almost every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$
$$(-\Delta)^{-1}f(x)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-2}{2}\right)}{4\pi^\frac{n}{2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}    \frac{1}{\left\lvert{x-y}\right\rvert^{n-2}}f(y)\mathrm{~d}y \in \dot{\mathrm{H}}^{2,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset \mathrm{L}^{\frac{pn}{n-2p}}(\mathbb{R}^n) \text{.} $$

I just finish my post here, saying that similarly one can define similarly homogeneous Sobolev spaces $\dot{\mathrm{H}}^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ but encounters the same kind of issues whenever $s\geqslant \frac{n}{p}$.

**[REFRENCES]**

> 1. *Bahouri, Hajer; Chemin, Jean-Yves; Danchin, Raphaël*, [**Fourier analysis and nonlinear partial differential equations**](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-16830-7), Grundlehren der Mathematischen Wissenschaften 343. Berlin: Heidelberg (ISBN 978-3-642-16829-1/hbk; 978-3-642-16830-7/ebook). xvi, 523 p. (2011). [ZBL1227.35004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1227.35004).
> 2. *Grafakos, Loukas*, [**Classical Fourier analysis**](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-09432-8), Graduate Texts in Mathematics 249. New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 978-0-387-09431-1/hbk). xvi, 489 p. (2008). [ZBL1220.42001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1220.42001).
> 3. *Grafakos, Loukas*, [**Modern Fourier analysis**](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4939-1230-8), Graduate Texts in Mathematics 250. New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 978-1-4939-1229-2/hbk; 978-1-4939-1230-8/ebook). xvi, 624 p. (2014). [ZBL1304.42002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1304.42002).

Comment: Thank you for the very elaborate and impressive answer! I would upvote this twice if I could! I will check out the books by Grafkakos, they seem to contain exactly what I am interested in.

Comment: Very nice read, thank you :)